# Intl.so extension not loading in Windows Google App Engine Php SDK

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-extension

I've created a PHP app for Google App engine which uses the PHP extension `intl.so`. I've loaded the extension by adding the following code to the `php.ini` in the app folder on my hard disk.

```
extension="intl.so"
```

My PHP script has the following code:

```
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
```

If I run the app local with the Google App Engine Launcher on Mac it works. On Windows I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function locale_accept_from_http() in ....

How do I load the extension in Windows?

Reinstall SDK didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the extension is called "php_intl.dll" on Windows by looking at the Google App Engine logs and searching the PHP folder. My php.ini now looks like this and it works on both Mac and Windows:

```
extension="intl.so"    
extension="php_intl.dll"
```